# Scrapy returns ValueError SelectorList is not supported

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I think the problem is when I try to enter each url spell with response.follow in the loop, but idk why, it passes the around 500 links perfectly to extract_xpath but only returns ValueError SelectorList is not supported

```
    def spell_parse(self, response):

        def extract_xpath(self, query):
            return response.xpath(query).get(Default = '')

    def parse(self, response):

        def extract_xpath(self, query):
            return response.xpath(query).get()

        for spell in response.xpath('//tr'):

            spell_def = spell.xpath('./td/a/@href')
            yield response.follow(spell_def, callback = self.spell_parse)

            yield {

                'Spell name': spell.xpath('./td[1]//text()').extract(),
                'School': spell.xpath('./td[2]//text()').extract(),
                'Casting time': spell.xpath('./td[3]//text()').extract(),
                'Range': spell.xpath('./td[4]//text()').extract(),
                'Duration': spell.xpath('./td[5]//text()').extract(),
                'Components': spell.xpath('./td[6]//text()').extract(),
                'Definition': extract_xpath('/p[4]//text()').extract(),
                'Levels': extract_xpath('/p[5]//text()').extract(),
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `get()` with `spell_def = spell.xpath('./td/a/@href')` like this `spell_def = spell.xpath('./td/a/@href').get()`, otherwise you will not pass the actual value of `href` to the follow function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).